# Vectorizing multiplication of matrices with different shapes in numpy/tensorflow

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, math, matrix, vectorization

I have a 4x4 input matrix and I want to multiply every 2x2 slice with a weight stored in a 3x3 weight matrix. Please see the attached image for an example:

[image]

In the image, the colored section of the 4x4 input matrix is multiplied by the same colored section of the 3x3 weight matrix and stored in the 4x4 output matrix. When the slices overlap, the output takes the sum of the overlaps (e.g. the blue+red).

I am trying to perform this operation in Tensorflow 2.0 using eager tensors (which can be treated as numpy arrays). This is what I've written to perform this operation and it produces the expected output.

```
inputm = np.ones([4,4]) # initialize 4x4 input matrix
weightm = np.ones([3,3]) # initialize 3x3 weight matrix
outputm = np.zeros([4,4]) # initialize blank 4x4 output matrix

# iterate through each weight
for i in range(weightm.shape[0]):
    for j in range(weightm.shape[1]):
        outputm[i:i+2, j:j+2] += weightm[i,j] * inputm[i:i+2, j:j+2]
```

However, I don't think this is efficient since I am iterating through the weight matrix one-by-one, and this will be extremely slow when I need to perform this on large matrices of 500x500. I am having a hard time identifying a way to vectorize this operation, maybe tiling the weight matrix to be the same shape as the input matrix and performing a single matrix multiplication. I have also thought about flattening the matrix but I'm still not able to see a way to do this more efficiently.

Any advice will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I think I have a solution but this involves using both numpy operations (e.g. `np.repeat`) and TensorFlow 2.0 operations (i.e. `tf.segment_sum`). And to warn you this is not the most clear elegant solution in the world, but it was the most elegant I could come up with. So here goes.

The main culprit in your problem is this weight matrix. If you manipulate this weight matrix to be a 4x4 matrix (with correct sum of weight at each position) you have a nice weight matrix which you can do an element-wise multiplication with the input. And that's my solution. Note that this is designed for the 4x4 problem and you should be able to relatively easily extend this to the 500x500 matrix.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[4,3,2,1],[1,2,3,4],[4,3,2,1]])
w = np.array([[5,4,3],[3,4,5],[5,4,3]])

# We make weights to a 6x6 matrix by repeating 2 times on both axis
w_rep = np.repeat(w,2,axis=0)
w_rep = np.repeat(w_rep,2,axis=1)

# Let's now jump in to tensorflow
tf_a = tf.constant(a)
tf_w = tf.constant(w_rep)
tf_segments = tf.constant([0,1,1,2,2,3])

# This is the most tricky bit, here we use the segment_sum to achieve what we need
# You can use segment_sum to get the sum of segments on the very first dimension of a matrix.
# So you need to do that to the input matrix twice. One on the original and the other on the transpose.

tf_w2 = tf.math.segment_sum(tf_w, tf_segments)
tf_w2 = tf.transpose(tf_w2)
tf_w2 = tf.math.segment_sum(tf_w2, tf_segments)
tf_w2 = tf.transpose(tf_w2)

print(tf_w2*a)
```

PS: I will try to include an illustration of what's going on here in a future edit. But I reckon that will take some time.

Comment: Thanks so much! I had never heard of tf.math.segment_sum before. I see that this works for a symmetric NxN matrix. To modify it for an NxM matrix where N != M, could I make two segments, something like this: `tf_w2 = tf.math.segment_sum(tf_w, tf_segments_horiz)`
`tf_w2 = tf.transpose(tf_w2)`
`tf_w2 = tf.math.segment_sum(tf_w2, tf_segments_vert)`
`tf_w2 = tf.transpose(tf_w2)`

Comment: Yes definitely you can. As long as the tensor that results in the `segment_sum` gives a weight matrix that has the same dimensions as the input tensor it should be fine. But as you pointed out `tf_segments_horiz` and `tf_segments_vert` need to be designed carefully!

Answer (score 0):

After realising @thushv89's trick, I realised you can get the same result by convolving the weight matrix with a matrix of ones:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

a = np.ones([4,4]) # initialize 4x4 input matrix
w = np.ones([3,3]) # initialize 3x3 weight matrix

b = np.multiply(a, convolve2d(w, np.ones((2,2))))

print(b)
```